# Converting accented/special characters from plain-text file to LaTeX representation using Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, latex

I have to read through a plain-text (UTF-8) file line-by-line and convert it into a .tex file (just another plain-text file with markup) for processing by a LaTeX processor.

One of the things I want to do is to convert special characters like é into their LaTeX representation: \'e

So I wrote:

```
with open(input, "r") as in_file, open(output, "w") as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
                # Other code here
                line.replace('é', "\\'e") # This fails as below
                # Other code here
                out_file.write(line)
```

running the script on an input file gives:

```
    line.replace('é', "\\'e")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So clearly the interpreter is using the `ascii` codec. Why?

Instead of the normal `open(...)` I also tried `codecs.open(input, "r", "utf-8")` and similarly for the output file, but get the same error.

Before running `line.replace(...)` I also tried using each of the following lines in turn (not both together, first one, then the other) to convert `line` to a unicode string:

```
line = unicode(line, "utf-8")
line = line.decode("utf-8")
```

but get exactly the same error.

What's the proper way to do it?

**Update 1:** I had already added `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` as the second line to the .py file before asking this question. Without it the interpreter would give the following error upon trying to run the script:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file <filename> on line 46, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Comment: I'm using the following package in Plone (CMS) to covert html to latex (then a pdf): https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.pdfgenerator/tree/master/ftw/pdfgenerator/html2latex This may not solve your problem you asked, but before you write everything new, you could probably get some code from this repo.

Comment: @Mathias in a quick look through the source code there it seems like they're not converting accented characters.

Comment: Well yes, I just saw converts all html entities to latex: https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.pdfgenerator/blob/master/ftw/pdfgenerator/html2latex/subconverters/htmlentities.py#L6 and https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.pdfgenerator/blob/master/ftw/pdfgenerator/utils.py#L37.

Comment: In the patterns I looked through in https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.pdfgenerator/blob/master/ftw/pdfgenerator/html2latex/patterns.py none of them referred to &eacute; (which is the only one I know from memory :-). Found references to &lsquo; and &rsquo; but not to &eacute;

Comment: Btw. there must be a issue with the source file. your code works with a txt file. http://pastebin.com/Zg7mM3qN

Comment: The source file is a plain-text UTF-8 encoded file. If I just comment out the lines that deal with accented characters from my script, everything works. Running the `file` command on the input file says: "UTF-8 Unicode English text, with very long lines"

Comment: @Mathias Thanks for your help... it was a very, very silly mistake on my part. Grrr....!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71331/discussion-between-mathias-and-markvgti).

Answer (score 1):

Probably a source issue. Try placing this at the top of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

For more information you can look here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: That's already done. Without that the Python interpreter wouldn't run a file with é in it.